# Creating an ArrayList Grocery List And Displaying Results in a table

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been working on this assignment for weeks and need some assistance. Please don't refer me to JavaDocs as I have reviewed them countless times and have been unable to find the solution to my program. 
This is what I need to do:

1. Add items to the ArrayList, one at a time, based on user typed input. The user will be prompted for the String to be stored in the ArrayList and then hit enter. The user will be able to continue to add items to the ArrayList until they just hit enter without typing anything.

Once the user does this (hits enter without typing anything), the program will display all of the elements of the ArrayList, both the index and String values, in a table. It will do this via a single loop

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// declares a name for the class
public class GroceryList2 {
    /**
     * Allows the program to be run and throws the Input-Output exception
     * error
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader userInput =
           new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//allows for input
        // declares the ArrayList to be a String
        ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        myArr.add("Milk");
        myArr.add("Cheese");
        myArr.add("Eggs");
        myArr.add("Bread"); //the values of the ArrayList already entereed
       // the loop that allows the criteria to run
        while(true) {
           if(myArr.isEmpty()== false ) {
              System.out.println("Enter the items for the grocery list: ");
              String item = in.next();//asks and allows for input
              myArr.add(item);
           }
           else if(myArr.isEmpty()== true ) {
              for (int i=0; i<myArr.size(); i++ ) {
                 // displays the list after the input
                 System.out.print(
                    "The Grocery List "+ i+ ": "+ myArr.get(i));
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

The code compiles, but when I just press enter, it doesn't display the grocery list, it waits for another entry.

Comment: You add elements to the list, and then you're surprised that the list is not empty?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Dumping your code here, especially homework, and asking "what's wrong?" is generally not productive nor is it a valid question per the FAQ. If you are confused as to why your code is not doing what you expect the debugger is a great place to start.

Comment: I find it interesting that this is supposed to be a forum that helps people, and yet a lot of people seem to come across as superior dicks. I asked for help because I've spent hours and weeks and am not able to find the solution that I'm looking for. I've tried altering the code as many ways as I know how, reviewed all of the docs and I don't understand, thus I"m asking for help. For future reference, this assignment is actually not for any credit, but for my own knowledge. If you aren't going to help that's fine, but then again you also could have just not answered.

Answer (score 0):

change the conditions in the if stattements, just swap them round. O rbetter improve by doing

```
if(myArr.isEmpty())
```

and then int he second

```
if(!myArr.isEmpty())
```

Comment: Thank you. As I'm trying to generate the list if the string for myArr is empty, should I be using .equals?

Comment: @CeceNichole isEmpty returns a boolean so you don;t have to anything to it, except what I wrote in my answer. Yes use .equals() for comparing anything that is a not a primitive

Comment: When I do that, it still doesn't allow the list to display if nothing is entered. I either get two responses depending on how I modify it. If I add a break, then the list displays immediately after I add one value. If I don't add a break, the loop runs and continues asking for an item to add for the list, but when I just press enter, it still awaits an entry and does not display the list.

Answer (score 0):

@Cece Inside the `while` loop you're not actually doing what you should in order to serve your purpose.

First of all, at every iteration the conditional `myArr.isEmpty()== false` will be validated (because your `myArr` array is never empty, as you already populate it before entering the `while` loop), so the execution of the code will go always to the same conditional branch. Just as a side note, you could write this more elegantly like this: `!myArr.isEmpty`.

Second, you're reading strings from the user, but all you do is add them to the array. As the `else` branch is never reached, the content of the array is never dumped. Just as a side note, the `if` statement after the `else` statement is redundant. You can safely remove it.

Third, the issue with your code is that you're never checking if the user input is empty. Instead, what you check is whether the groceries array is empty or not.

This is how I'd write the `while` loop:

```
while(true){
    String item = in.next();
    if(item.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The Grocery List: ");
        for(int i=0; i<myArr.size(); i++) {
             System.out.println(i + ": "+ myArr.get(i));
        }
        break;
    }
    else{
        myArr.add(item);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand any part of my code.